# jQuery ajax submit 2 data sources (form & datatables)

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a form that I'm submiting with jQuery ajax which works fine but I also need to submit a second data source.

this is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(window).load(function(){     
        // this is the ID of your FORM tag
        $j("#send-form").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // this disables the submit button so the user stays on the page
            // this collects all of the data submitted by the form
            var str = $j(this).serialize();                  
               $j.ajax({               
               type: "POST", // the kind of data we are sending
               url: "<?php print $cs_base_dir; ?>sendmail.php", // this is the file that processes the form data
               data: str, sData, // this is our serialized data from the form
               success: function(msg){  // anything in this function runs when the data has been successfully processed

                    // this sets up our notification area for error / success messages
                    $j("#note").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                    { 
                        if(msg == "OK") // Message Sent? Show the Thank You message and hide the form
                        {
                            // This is shown when everything goes okay
                            result = "<div id=\"message\" class=\"updated\">Your message has been sent.</div>";

                        }
                        else // if there were ewrrors
                        {
                            result = msg; // msg is defined in sendmail.php
                        }                                
                        $j(this).html(result); // display the messages in the #note DIV                          
                    });                  
                }                    
             });                     
        });         
    });
</script>
```

But I also have some other data (datatables) I need to submit as well which I get with this:

```
var sData = $j('input', oTable.fnGetNodes()).serialize();
```

This is the page that specifies how to sent it: [DataTables with form elements example](http://datatables.net/examples/api/form.html)

How do I add this so both form and datatables are submitted?

Thanks
C

Comment: found this: `data: { json_1:$.toJSON(data_1), json_2:$.toJSON(data_2) },
` is this what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
data: str + "&" + sData
```

Both str and sData are sent as strings which, taken from the example on the DataTables page, look like this: "check8=8&check9=9". 
So you just add the "&" in between them to send both.